# Test multiple conditions in javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to test multiple conditions in a javascript switch statement? For example:

```
switch (var1 && var2) {
    case var1 == 1 || var2 == 1:
        alert("1");
        break;
    case var1 == 2 || var2 == 2:
        alert("2");
        break;
        //etc...
}
```

The reason I am asking is because this would be a lot easier than using tons of if or switch statements.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: Time goes and we receive new information. So here is an example of testing of multiple conditions in switch:

```
let var1 = 2;
let var2 = 2;

switch(true) {
    case var1 === 1 || var2 === 1:
        console.log('1');
        break;
    case var1 === 2 || var2 === 2:
        console.log('2');
        break;
}
```

This tricky approach was found in [You Don't Know JS: Types & Grammar](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch5.md#switch).
I highly recommend the whole series by the way.

**Original Answer**: No. It is not possible. Please see [switch statement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's `switch` is fairly limited in what it can do, but that's not to say you can't get creative:

```
switch ([ var1, var2 ].join(',')) {
  case '1,1':
    alert("1");
    break;
  case '2,2':
    alert("2");
    break;
}
```

Here combining the two values with something like a comma means you have a *single value* you can then `switch` on. The `switch` itself can handle several different matches for the same branch, but the matches have to be very simple:

```
  case '1,1':
  case '1,2':
  case '1,3':
    // ...
    break;
```

Where here any of those will follow the same branch.

If you're looking for something where *either* `var1` or `var2` can be a particular value, then it's time for an alternate approach using a look-up table:

```
let alerts = {
  '1': '1',
  '2': '2'
};

let var1 = 3;
let var2 = 2;

let hit = [ var1, var2 ].some(v => {
  if (alerts[v]) {
    alert(alerts[v]);
    return true;
  }
});
```

Here you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find the first matching value in your array of possible values to test.

Remember that within the context of `switch` each condition is evaluated before the switching happens. It isn't evaluated like an `if` is because `switch` is meant to follow one branch and one branch only. `if` chains necessarily go from one to the next until one triggers.

Comment: And what about `var 2 ==1`¿ would that work for the OP

Comment: @AlonEitan `var1` and `var2` are combined into a singular value here.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that the question was edited into a more correct js syntax :)

Comment: @AlonEitan I've added some more text about interpreting that initial code as an *A OR B* thing instead of *A AND B*.

Answer (score 0):

It's not posible, because it will need to validate more than one value and that is not supporter by switch statement.

My advice would it be: separate the "or" conditions and create some x number of functions and then call them from each separate case statement as you need.

If you need to do the same in several case statements, call the same function on each case statement.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, switch statements don't work this way. This won't throw an error, but it won't produce your intended results. (var1 && var2) evaluates to true. So your first case is testing for True == (var1==1 || var 2==1).

Instead you could maybe do nested statements:

```
switch (var1){ 
  case 1:

     switch (var2){
         case 1:
            alert ("1")
            break;
     }
     // ...
}
//...
```

However in this case, I would opt for nested if statements for clarity